# How to directly get Node instead of NodePath in export variable?

Tags: godot, gdscript

Instead of maintaining 2 separate variables for my exported node path, like this:

```
extends Node2D

export(NodePath) var target_path
var target_node

func _ready():
    target_node=get_node(target_path)
```

is there any way to export only 1 variable and directly get the node?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is, and it's a one liner:

```
extends Node2D
export (NodePath) onready var target_node=get_node(target_node)
```

Turns out someone did it [2 years ago](https://www.reddit.com/r/godot/comments/kuagbx/exportnodepath_onready_var_some_node_get_nodesome/).

Answer (score 2):

Godot 4 with GDScript 2 offers an even more concise way to export only one variable and directly get a node.

```
@export var target_node: Node
```

This also offers the advantage of setting constraints on the type of the node, where `Node` could be replaced by `Node2D`, `Control`, or even a node with a script attached that you've defined using `class_name`.

```
@export var camera: Camera2D
@export var fancy_camera: MyCamera2D
```

Answer (score 0):

With Godot4 Script the one-liner doesn't work anymore, as you'd write:

```
@export_node_path @onready var target_node=get_node(target_node)
```

which produces these errors:

```
Could not resolve member "target_node": Cyclic reference.
"@export_node_path" annotation requires a variable of type "NodePath" but type "Node" was given instead.
The "@onready" annotation will make the default value to be set after the "@export" takes effect and will override it. (Warning treated as error.)
```

So you'll have to write **2 lines**:

```
@export_node_path var target_node
@onready var _target_node = get_node(target_node)
```